# React native Application with Tensorflow , mediapippe, cvzone

Tags: android, react-native, mediapipe, tflite, cvzone

I am going to create a sign language recognition mobile application using React Native. I have already trained the model using Mediapipe and cvzone. but media pipe can not use directly for react native application? how can I do it? I am a beginner at react native.

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t React just a framework for JS?  I think you can call MediaPipe and CVzone can be called as a JS libaries to load your trained modules.

Answer (score 0):

To use mediapipe in my app I have created a python api and call the api from react native.